# Using regex for locate and grep to get only folders

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression, locate

When I try to search using `locate` and `grep` something like:

```
locate A-B | grep .dir
```

The result is:

```
.../A-B-C.dir
.../A-B-C.dir/file
.../A-B-C.dir/file1
.../A-B-D.dir
.../A-B-D.dir/file1
...
```

How to modify `grep` or `locate` to make the search finished with `.dir` and nothing more?

I have quite old system:

> Secure Locate 2.7 - Released January 24, 2003
>
> grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Linux system, then chances are that you `locate` supports regular expressions:

```
locate --regex 'A-B.*\.dir$'
```

If not,

```
locate 'A-B' | grep '\.dir$'
```

The main point is to anchor the regular expression to the end of the line properly with `$`.

Note that both of these variations would also find e.g. `/some/path/ABBA-Bootlegs/thing.dir`.

Comment: The second option is working. The first results empty line.

Comment: @XuMuK It may be that your `locate` does not support the `--regex` flag then (see the manual on your system).

Comment: according to `man locate` it should work with regex.

Comment: It's easier with the default wildcards anyway: `locate '*A-B*.dir'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in my case `Secure Locate 2.7 - Released January 24, 2003` this is not working. The Linux is too old, but it is impossible to update it.